# Converter file service on ubuntu server

Tags: django, ubuntu, pdf, converters, docx

I'm using python/django on ubuntu server and exporting PDF's

There's a way to use a service to converte those PDF's to MS Word files?

Or maybe HTML to PDF/DOC/DOCX

The point is avoid making 3 different programs when I can use a converter.

Thanks

Comment: using wkhtmltopdf you can convert html to pdf, they also have a python API. i've done this already, it works very well. http://wkhtmltopdf.org/ https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pdfkit/0.5.0

Comment: I have a html to pdf service actually working. I can´t find a service than works like that but with MS Word formats.